# Lookup multiple column from a single table

Tags: r, data.table

Suppose that I have the following data

```
df <- structure(list(car_model = c(301, 302, 303, 304), colour = c(501, 
502, 503, 504), sales = c(182, 191, 302, 101)), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

and I have a single lookup table where I will get the texts to replace the codes in the columns `car_model` and `colour`.

```
tbl1 <- structure(list(txt = c("A", "B", "C", "Y"), cod = c(301, 302, 
303, 304), var = c("car_model", "car_model", "car_model", "car_model"
)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
tbl2 <- structure(list(txt = c("black", "green", "red", "white"), cod = c(501, 
502, 503, 504), var = c("colour", "colour", "colour", "colour"
)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

combining the two tables I have

```
tbl <- rbind(tbl1,tbl2)
# A tibble: 8 x 3
  txt     cod var      
  <chr> <dbl> <chr>    
1 A       301 car_model
2 B       302 car_model
3 C       303 car_model
4 Y       304 car_model
5 black   501 colour   
6 green   502 colour   
7 red     503 colour   
8 white   504 colour
```

Is there a way to replace all the columns in the main `df` using the lookup table this way (matching the column names by the value in the columns `var` and `cod`) or I need to make separate tables, one for each variable? Another doubt that I have is if it's reasonable to do it in a dataset with ~10 million rows, 30 or more variables and a lookup table with total size ~ 5 thousand rows.

EDIT: About the codes is possible to have the same code in different variables.

EDIT2: I'm looking for a fast and memory efficient solution. Maybe some solution with `data.table`

Comment: Are the `cod`s unique? What I want to know: is `301` always a car_model and `501` always a colour or it is possible, that there is car_model named `501`?

Comment: @MartinGal no the codes are not unique, is possible to have a `car_model` with the same code that a `colour`. The codes are unique just for each variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way with [`tidyverse`](https://www.tidyverse.org/)

1. Loop [`across`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html) the columns found in the `unique` values from 'var' column of 'tbl'
2. Get the column name of looped column with [`cur_column()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/context.html) to create a logical expression on the 'var' column of 'tbl' ('i1')
3. Use `match` to get the position index where the column values match with subset of 'cod' column of 'tbl'
4. Extract the corresponding 'txt' column of 'tbl' from the subset based on 'i1'

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% 
    mutate(across(all_of(unique(tbl$var)),
     ~ {i1 <- tbl$var == cur_column()
       tbl$txt[i1][match(., tbl$cod[i1])]}))
```

-output

```
df
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  car_model colour sales
  <chr>     <chr>  <dbl>
1 A         black    182
2 B         green    191
3 C         red      302
4 Y         white    101
```

---

Or with [`data.table`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html), we may use the same method

1. Created a named vector from 'tbl' ('nm1')
2. Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT`)
3. Specify the columns of interest in `.SDcols` from the `unique` element of 'var'
4. Do the `match` by looping with `Map` and assign (`:=`) the output back to the original columns

```
library(data.table)
nm1 <- setNames(tbl$txt, tbl$cod)
un1 <- unique(tbl$var)
setDT(df)[, (un1) := Map(function(x, y) 
     nm1[tbl$var == y][as.character(x)], .SD,  un1), .SDcols = un1]
```

-output

```
df
   car_model colour sales
1:         A  black   182
2:         B  green   191
3:         C    red   302
4:         Y  white   101
```

---

Or may use `base R`

```
lst1 <- with(tbl, split(setNames(txt, cod), var))
df[un1] <- Map(function(x, y)  y[as.character(x)], df[un1], lst1)
```

Comment: Thanks akrun, is there a way to do it with `data.table` ? Is dplyr more memory efficient and fast than data.table for it?

Answer (score 2):

A `data.table` option

```
cbind(unstack(setDT(tbl)[melt(
  setDT(df)[, .(car_model, colour)], ,
  variable.name = "var",
  value.name = "cod"
), .(txt, var), on = .(var, cod)]), df[, .(sales)])
```

gives

```
  car_model colour sales
1         A  black   182
2         B  green   191
3         C    red   302
4         Y  white   101
```

Answer (score 2):

You can reshape the data and perform the join.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -sales) %>%
  left_join(tbl, by = c('name' = 'var', 'value' = 'cod')) %>%
  select(-value) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = txt)

#  sales car_model colour
#  <dbl> <chr>     <chr> 
#1   182 A         black 
#2   191 B         green 
#3   302 C         red   
#4   101 Y         white
```